# Displaying success alert on clicking with javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

```
<div id="success">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" type="submit" id="btnShow">Send</button>
</div>
```

I am not able to write javascript(facing errors, as i am new to javascript) to display success alert on click event.

the script i wrote is :

```
$("#btnShow").click(function(){

  $(".alert").show();
});
```

Comment: What are the errors you are facing?

Comment: @Mamum alert text is visible before click, i tried css ```display: None``` but didn't worked.

Comment: can you show the javascript you have written thus far?

Comment: Please update the question with all the relevant code.

Comment: Since you're looking for the bootstrap alert, you need to add the `alert` class to your button classes. For example:  `<button class="alert btn btn-primary btn-x1">`

Comment: @bruh if i add that ```alert``` class the whole button becomes invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy as this:

```html
<script>
  function success() {
    alert("success!");
  }
</script>
<div id="success">
  <button onclick=success() class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" type="submit" id="btnShow">Send</button>
</div>
```

Elements can have an `onclick` property, with a function's name.

Comment: i wanted to bootstrap alert https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/ like this

Comment: Just remember the quotes around the `"success()"` call, on the `onclick` attribute

Comment: If the bootstrap alert isn't working as they show in their docs even though you followed everything as you should, go and check if you have all of their CSS and JS/jQuery CDNs imported in your HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a simple built-in java script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('button#btnShow').click(function(){
          alert("Success");
       });
    });
</script>
```